# Access extra variable from LoggerAdapter in custom Handler

Tags: python, logging

I have a custom LoggingAdapter, to which I'm passing a call_id variable.

```py
# The adapter itself
class FreeSWITCHLoggingAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return "[%s] %s" % (self.extra["call_id"], msg), kwargs

# And this is how we initialize it
logger = FreeSWITCHLoggingAdapter(
    logging.getLogger(__name__), {"call_id": "some context specific ID here"}
)
logger.info("something related to a call")
```

On the logger, I have also added a custom handler, that would need access to that call_id.

```py
class FreeSWITCHLoggingHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        # How can I access extra or call_id here?
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by going through the source code of the LoggerAdapter itself.

The LoggerAdapter has a process method defined:

```py
def process(self, msg, kwargs):
    kwargs["extra"] = self.extra
    return msg, kwargs
```

Which essentially makes the data available on the record. So I don't really need my own class, I just used the default adapter:

```py
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(
    root_logger, {"call_id": session.getVariable("uuid")}
)
```

And that way I managed to hook up the built-in logging of Python with the specifics of FreeSWITCH:

```py
class FreeSWITCHLoggingHandler(logging.Handler):
    # Map Python log levels to FreeSWITCH log levels
    FS_LOG_LEVEL_MAP {
        "CRITICAL": "crit",
        "ERROR": "err",
        "WARNING": "warning",
        "INFO": "info",
        "DEBUG": "debug",
        "NOTSET": "console"
    }

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        # Map to a FreeSWITCH log level
        fs_log_level = FS_LOG_LEVEL_MAP[record.levelname]

        if hasattr(record, "call_id"):
            consoleLog(fs_log_level, "[%s] %s" % (record.call_id, str(msg)) + "\n")
        else:
            consoleLog(fs_log_level, str(msg) + "\n")
```

As you can see `record.call_id` is now available.